# What happens to open sessions when changing password in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say in PostgreSQL, there are open sessions for a particular user, what happens to them, when a password is changed?

I think something of the following:

1. It is not allowed to issue password change command
2. All sessions are
   terminated after completing the last query
3. Open sessions will
   continue to work until closed explicitly or by timeout.

Comment: Open sessions will continue to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing happens to open sessions, they continue to work normally. There's no way to tell what authentication method was used to establish a session or what password was used.

If you want to boot off users who *may* have used an old password you'll need to `pg_terminate_backend` all backends for that user.